# Use Page Object Pattern with promise in Protractor

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, protractor, e2e-testing

I have two classes:

```
LayerWrapper
Layer
```

which are page objects.

I want to rework the method:

```
export class LayerPanel {
    public static layers = element.all(by.automationId('layer'));

    public static findLayerByName(layerName: string): Promise<boolean> {
        return this.layers.filter((elem) => {
            return elem.getText().then(text => {
                return text === layerName;
            });
        }).first().then(this.OK, this.Failed);
     }

    private static OK() {
        return new Promise<true>();
    }

    private static Failed {
        console.log('not found');
    }
}
```

I want to refactor it, so that I would return a Layer page object:

```
public static findLayerByName(layerName: string): Promise<Layer> {
    return this.layers.filter((elem) => {
        return elem.getText().then(text => {
            return text === layerName;
        });
    }).first().then(this.OK, this.Failed);
}

private static OK() {
    return new Promise<Layer>();
}
```

it seems to be ok, but maybe this could be done in a better way ?

Comment: Are you sure that your code is working? Seems to be that your work with the promises shouldn't work.

Comment: could you tell why ?

Comment: You construct a new instance of `Promise` without passing the needed function, should be: `new Promise<true>((resolve, reject) => { ... })`, that's strange for me, but maybe you're using an implementation for promises which supports that

Answer (score 3):

Create an object function and declare all related page functions/methods in it and then do module.exports=new PageName(). This is best practice to send a page(Layer) object. You can follow below code:

```
  var LayerPanel function(){

  this.layers = element.all(by.automationId('layer'));

  this.findLayerByName=function(layerName){
               return this.layers.filter((elem) => {
                  return elem.getText().then(text => {
                          return text === layerName;
                     });
   }).first();
 };

 this.OK() {
    return new Promise<true>();
   }

 this.Failed {
  console.log('not found');
   }    
};

module.exports = new LayerPanel();
```

Comment: but I want to return a new Layer from the findLayerByName. The export thing I have with typescript export class

Comment: @JerzyGruszka, i have updated code which will retrun an element which matched given layerName